# Allowing mobile functions to be used on a website?

Tags: mobile, native, responsive-design

Is it possible to allow native functions on a website? For example:

My site is responsive and when it's loaded by mobile browsers (based on media-queries) can I get ride of the search box and allow the user to pull up a native search using a button.

I can handle media-queries, detection, etc. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use a devices search function within the site.

Comment: Native search? I think you should stick with the site search. There are a few HTML functions that offer similar to native features (geo location, camera access on opera labs browser) but to access iOS native functions (camera, maps, accelerometer) you need to look at something like phonegap which then goes down the app path.